# slackのcustom絵文字を作った人を取得したい

Tags: python, web-scraping, slack

slackで各custom絵文字を誰が作ったのかをしたいと思っています。
apiではemojiのリストを取得することができますが、誰が作ったのかを取得できません。
そこで、https://team.slack.com/customize/emoji
をスクレイピングして取得したく思っています。（NameとAddedBy）
pythonでどのように処理すれば良いのかご教示ください。

### 試したこと

https://qiita.com/penta515/items/6f6c077057f316712eb3
を参考にログインした後、

```
r = session.get('https://team.slack.com/customize/emoji')
r.text
```

で見たところ、うまく取得できていないようです。
よろしくお願いします。